# Keyboard shortcuts for Titanium IDE in MAC

Tags: titanium, keyboard-shortcuts, appcelerator

I'm new to appcelerator titanium IDE, previously I was working on Xcode.

In xcode I'm relied on the keyboard shortcuts for saving my coding time.

Now I'm struggling with titanium, because I don't know any keyboard shortcuts in titanium IDE.
In Xcode commenting a block of code (`cmd+\`), shifting them to left(`cmd+}`) or right(`cmd+{`) was very easy. In titanium now I'm manually doing it for each line of code !

Can anybody help me to find the shortcuts for titanium IDE in MAC ?

If this is not the right place to ask this question. please pardon me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Midhun, Titanium IDE is just same as Eclipse IDE and simple. I've given some important shortcuts below

- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> for commenting a block of code
- <kbd>tab</kbd> for moving a block of statement to right
- <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> for move a block of code to left
- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> for run your project
- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> for debug your project
- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> for toggle breakpoint
- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Find and Replace

You can use [this](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Modifying+your+shortcut+keys) link to modify your keyboard shortcuts for Titanium Studio in windows and in editor window, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>Cmd</kbd>  + <kbd>L</kbd> to see all available shortcuts. Comment, uncomment and toggle comment are there. It tells all the shortcut for titanium studio

Happy programming:)

Comment: Thanks for the extensive anser, Anand! However, in Titanium Studio 3.2.0 for Mac, there is no way to set the 'comment' shortcut. It's just not in the list of commands whose shortcut you can set. Thankfully Cmd + / does work (though it's not in the list)

Comment: In Titanium Studio 3.2.0 for Mac cmd + shift + F11 does not work. No solution yet.