# How can I type console.log('') or Ti.API.info('') in titanium by hitting single key

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I am tired of writing console.log('') or TI.API.info('') many times in my code and then deleting it several time.

Is there a setting in Titanium where I can hit a shortcut key like Alt + C or something and this writes the console statement in my code snippet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

write `inf` and then press Control + space bar it will print `Ti.API.info('')`.

and pressing cmd + d will delete the current line.

for more please see [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080374/keyboard-shortcuts-for-titanium-ide-in-mac), [Link2](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Modifying+your+shortcut+keys), [Link3](http://fokkezb.nl/2013/05/20/titanium-studio-shortcuts/)